# Is it possible to tell which row failed on commit with IRowsetFastLoad?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, oledb

We're using IRowsetFastLoad to load batches of 500 rows at a time into a SQL Server database. Sometimes a batch fails on commit due to bad data, for example, there was a primary key violation or a floating point column had a NaN value. Is there a way to tell which row caused the failure so we can successfully retry and load the remaining 499 good rows?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the short answer to the question is no, there is no way to tell which row created the error and there is no way to manipulate the rows after failure.

However, there is the GetErrorInfo function to retrieve a useful error message.